# Create java program / export as jar without any dpi scaling?

Tags: java, jar, jframe, swt, windowbuilder

Is it possible to turn off dpi scaling in my program/export it as non dpi scaling support? I have made a program using swt windowbuilder with eclipse, and it gets messed up on different dpi resolutions.

Is the only way to go about this to use something like MigLayout? 
If so, can anyone point me on how to use that?

The program gets messed up with different dpi settings (and text scaling)

I haven't found anything very helpful in this subject, other than people giving advice on how to make the program dpi scale able. (which i do not need in this case, and would prefer it just be disabled if possible)

Comment: `"i've searched all over the internet and cannot find the answer."` -- some comments have high risk of inducing down-votes and close-votes, and I'm doing you a favor by telling you that this is one of them. Why? It tells us absolutely **nothing** of use, only that you haven't yet found a solution (we know that, else you wouldn't be asking). Instead, I suggest you remove this and show more concrete information about exactly what you **did** find, and how it's not helping you. Use the information you've gathered to make your question as specific and asl clear as possible.

Comment: I do think it's reasonable to put that in because I do want the helpful people to know i have tried and researched extensively before asking this question..but am updating it now

Comment: @ateaparrot Can you please explain why you prefer forcing a certain dpi over using a proper layout that would take care of everything for you?

Comment: @Baz i just don't understand what you mean, i've tried using a form layout and nothing changes, same problems occur. Different dpi the whole gui is messed up